# How to create a React Loop inside a component for LI items containing a picture and URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I loop through the Social Media icons LI items including URL and image? My code is not working.. i don't know why?

```
import React from 'react';

import iconFB from 'images/socials/facebook_logo.svg';
import iconIG from 'images/socials/insta_logo.svg';
import iconTW from 'images/socials/twitter_logo.svg';
import iconYT from 'images/socials/youtube_logo.svg';

const Social = () => {

    const icons = [
        { link: 'http://www.facebook.com', image: `${iconFB}`},
        { link: 'http://www.instagram.com', image: `${iconIG}`},
        { link: 'http://www.twitter.com', image: `${iconTW}`},
        { link: 'http://www.youtube.com', image: `${iconYT}`}
    ]

    return(
        <ul className="social">
            {
                icons.map((a, b, c) => {
                    return <li key={a}><a href={a} target="_blank"><img src={c}/></a></li>
                })
            }
        </ul>
    )
}

export default Social;
```

Comment: You need to put them in an array in order to loop through them.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const socialNetworks = [
  { url: 'http://www.facebook.com', icon: iconFB },
  ...
];

const Social = () => (
  <ul>
    {
      socialNetworks.map(({ url, icon }) => (
        <li key={url}><a href={url} target="_blank"><img src={icon} /></a></li>
      ))
    }
  </ul>
);
```